# Adding pooled connection datasource in JBoss 7

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss

I am changing from Glassfish to Jboss 7. I have configured a datasource in the Glassfish server which is pooled at the server, but not XA. I am trying this, but each time I open admin web gui the driver element is truncated to `<driver name="postgresql" .. />`. Something must be wrong since I can't log on to my application. How can I configure a datasource which is pooled on JBoss 7?

```
            <drivers>
                <driver name="postgresql" module="org.postgresql">
                    <datasource-class>org.postgresql.ds.PGConnectionPoolDataSource</datasource-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
```

This is the module.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.postgresql">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="postgresql-9.2-1002.jdbc4.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

Comment: This is explained here: [Data Source Configuration in AS 7](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/DataSourceConfigurationInAS7). If you need more help, ask for support in their forum.

Answer (score 0):

In you domain.xml/standalone.xml you can specify your datasource:

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.1">
        <datasources>
            <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</connection-url>
                <driver>h2</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>sa</user-name>
                    <password>sa</password>
                </security>
            </datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                    <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
        </datasources>
    </subsystem>
```